# UCSC BLAT output python

Tags: python, blat

Is there a way I can get the position number of the mismatch from the following BLAT result using Python?

```
00000001 taaaagatgaagtttctatcatccaaaaaatgggctacagaaacc 00000045
<<<<<<<< |||||||||||||||||||||||||||  |||||||||||||||| <<<<<<<<
41629392 taaaagatgaagtttctatcatccaaagtatgggctacagaaacc 41629348
```

As we can see, there are two mismatches in the above output. Can we get the position number of the mismatch/mutation using Python. This is how it appears in the source code also. So I'm a little confused on how to proceed. 
Thank you.

Comment: Do you want the position in the top or bottom sequence? Both?

Comment: I want it from the bottom sequence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the mismatches using the `.find` method of a string. Mismatches are indicated by a space (' '), so we look for that in the middle line of the blat output. I don't know blat personally, so I'm not sure if the output always comes in triplet lines, but assuming it does, the following function will return a list of positions mismatching, each position represented as a tuple of the mismatching position in the top sequence, and the same in the bottom sequence.

```
blat_src = """00000001 taaaagatgaagtttctatcatccaaaaaatgggctacagaaacc 00000045
<<<<<<<< |||||||||||||||||||||||||||  |||||||||||||||| <<<<<<<<
41629392 taaaagatgaagtttctatcatccaaagtatgggctacagaaacc 41629348"""

def find_mismatch(blat):
    #break the blat input into lines
    lines = blat.split("\n")

    #give some firendly names to the different lines
    seq_a = lines[0]
    seq_b = lines[2]

    #We're not interested in the '<' and '>' so we strip them out with a slice
    matchstr = lines[1][9:-9]

    #Get the integer values of the starts of each sequence segment
    pos_a = int(seq_a[:8])
    pos_b = int(seq_b[:8])

    results = []

    #find the index of first space character, mmpos = mismatch position
    mmpos = matchstr.find(" ")
    #if a space exists (-1 if none found)
    while mmpos != -1:
        #the position of the mismatch is the start position of the
        #sequence plus the index within the segment
        results.append((posa+mmpos, posb+mmpos))
        #search the rest of the string (from mmpos+1 onwards)
        mmpos = matchstr.find(" ", mmpos+1)
    return results

print find_mismatch(blat_src)
```

Which produces

```
[(28, 41629419), (29, 41629420)]
```

Telling us positions 28 and 29 (indexed according to the top sequence) or positions 41629419 and 41629420 (indexed according to the bottom sequence) are mismatched.